# Will my photos still be saved on icloud if I turn off 'find my iphone' from the icloud?

Tags: ios

Will I still be able to access my photos, contacts, etc by logging into my icloud if I turn off 'find my iphone'?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is no impact from turning off "Find my iPhone" besides you losing the ability to track your phone should it be misplaced/lost/stolen/etc. To prevent syncing of all items, you would need to turn off iCloud altogether on your phone (or its individual services).